# Mathematica 13.3 forgot integral defining Bessel functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I installed the newest version of Mathematica 13.3.0.0 on Mac. It looks like it forgot how to compute a simple integral

```
Integrate[Cos[n t - z Sin[t]], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

which the previous versions had no difficulty with (it's the Bessel function times $\pi$). I've also noticed a similar problem with the modified Bessel functions before.

I am wondering if this is a general problem.

Comment: Interestingly, this identity is on [Wolfram's own functions database website](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/07/01/01/0006/) but doesn't appear to be recognized by Mathematica (even if we include `Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]`.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert This seems to be the case for many special functions and integer parameters. They integrate for an explicit integer value but not a general one. Oddly the OP's integral works with `Assumptions -> 5 <= n <= 5 && n \[Element] Integers` but not with `Assumptions -> 4 < n <= 5 && n \[Element] Integers`. I'm wondering what earlier version of *Mma* did not have trouble. The issues seems familiar to me for a long time now.

Comment: Admins referred to a question answered before, which does not address my question. It looks like there is a bug in the new Mathematica version.

Comment: Which previous versions? Version 10.2 can't do it.

Comment: I certainly remember that all versions before 13 had no such problem.